# Realtime listener for dynamic list firebase - Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

A dynamic list of users is being populated with users from firebase DB. But when any value is changed for any of the user, it does not reflect on client side as there is not listener for it.

```
//Loop for All Users
var anotherUserId = snapshot.key;
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/"+anotherUserID);
ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   var obj = snapshot.val();
   li += '    <div class="contacts-container '+obj.status+'">';
   li += '        <h3>'+obj.fname+' '+obj.lname+'</h3>';
 });
//Loop Ends
```

If status is changed for one user, it does not reflect on client side **Until i refresh the page**.

This is what i am trying to make[image]

So, if any user's status in DB changes it should change class in the **DIV** to toggle online signal. (Grey or Green)

Basically realtime variables are not working but with refresh it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to listen to changes to the user database with the `child_changed` event. You can then add an id to the div to so you can select the one that changed and update the class. 
Something to this effect:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");

ref.on('child_changed', function(snapshot){
 var changedUser = snapshot.val();
 document.getElementById(changedUser.id).classList.toggle('active');
}
```

Comment: And It Worked, Thanks A Bundle Sir :) Salute